# How to get around Cannot Enumerate More than once using two queries

Tags: c#

The below code is throwing a "Cannot Enumerate More Than Once" on the second ToList().  What is the best approach for fixing this error?

```
var firstQuery = (from r in db.SomeProcedure(Id)
                       select new MyClass
                       {
                            Id = r.Id,
                            Name = r.Name,
                            Company= r.Company,
                            Title = r.Title
                       });

        var secondQuery = (from d in firstQuery
                          group d by d.Title into groupedTitles
                         select new MyClass2
                         {                                 
                             Title = groupedTitles.Key,  //How To include the Id                                  
                         });

          List<MyClass> mClass = firstQuery.ToList();
          Th Below ToList() is throwing a cannot enumerate more than one
          List<MyClass2> mClass2 = secondQuery.ToList();
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your first query to a list right away.

```
var firstQuery = (from r in db.SomeProcedure(Id)
                   select new MyClass
                   {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Company= r.Company,
                        Title = r.Title
                   }).ToList();

    var secondQuery = (from d in firstQuery
                      group d by d.Title into groupedTitles
                     select new MyClass2
                     {                                 
                         Title = groupedTitles.Key,  //How To include the Id                                  
                     });

      List<MyClass> mClass = firstQuery;
      List<MyClass2> mClass2 = secondQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: That will not support server-side queries for the 2nd query.

Comment: @usr indeed - that is a limitation.